# Why this one of my answer is removed:: "Could not start the command:" probably because the filename has two spaces?

Tags: discussion, answers

In [This post on the solution of "Could not start the command:"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95058), I wrote the answer:

> Another probable situation is you (maybe unintentionally) typed two consecutive spaces ' ' in the file name. If you require your filename to have two consecutive spaces for some reason, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529144)

But it was deleted. I think my answer neither coincides with others', nor is off-topic. (I met the situation myself, and has consulted to the first post. Therefore I add the answer to add one possibility.) Why is it downvoted and removed?

Comment: There aren't any deleted answers below the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529144

Comment: I think you meant post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95058/error-texstudio-could-not-start-command/702515

Comment: It's deleted from review: I suspect hat the reviewers felt that it's more of a comment (as you are taking a guess).

Comment: If you are instead referring to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95058/36296 : From the error message one can see that the file name is `texstudio_qH5268.tex`, no spaces and especially not two spaces in a row, so not sure how "probable" this situation is

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I mis-reversed the link.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you. I did not know `texstudio_qH5268.tex` is the filename. Therefore my answer is off-topic.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz May I ask an extensive question: Is there any appropriate way to let the users who typed two consecutive spaces ' ' realize this when they read the first post (i.e the post of which my answer was removed)? When I made such mistake and searched the error message, this is the first result. I think it will be more convenient if the first post can suggest other possible situations.

Comment: @JosephWright It seems one can not reply two users in one comment. So I have two send two. Would you suggest an appropriate way to let the users who typed two consecutive spaces ' ' realize this when they read the first post (i.e the post of which my answer was removed)?

Comment: @Asigan Users can avoid the problem with consecutive spaces easily: don't use spaces in file names, they are evil and cause problems in a number of tools.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Fine. Thanks for your suggestion!